# ngx-bootstrap + angular 6 + datepicker

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, datepicker, angular-6

Olá,

Estou utilizando o datepicker do ngx-bootstrap pela primeira vez e estou encontrando algumas dificuldades.

Uma delas é que ao selecionar a data desejada, meu input fica no formato exato que eu preciso, da seguinte maneira: '20/12/2018', porém quando jogo no console o valor do input, é apresentado da seguinte maneira: 'Thu Dec 20 2018 23:26:21 GMT-0200 (Horário de Verão de Brasília)'.

Como eu faço para deixar o valor do input com o formato brasileiro: '20/12/2018'. Procurei na documentação do mesmo e não encontrei.

Evidencias de como está funcionando(errado).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Evidencia das propriedades:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: De que forma vc jogou no console o valor do input?

Comment: Como é reactiveForms, coloquei dessa forma: console.log(this.formulario.controls.data.value);

Comment: Cara, coloque `console.log(this.formulario.controls.data)` e veja nas propriedades se tem algo com `20/12/2018`.

Comment: Procurei também e não achei, se quiser, posso mandar o print com a evidencia

Comment: Editei a pergunta e inseri a foto

Comment: Conhece outro datepicker que funciona bem?

Comment: Cara, conheço muito não. Tenta assim: `var dia = this.formulario.controls.data.value;
console.log(dia.getDate()+"/"+Number(dia.getMonth()+1)+"/"+dia.getFullYear());
`

Comment: Boooa, assim foi...Cria uma resposta ai que dou ok

Comment: Guilherme, estou encontrando dificuldades para que o input fique no formato correto, se puder dar uma olhada nesta pergunta seria de grande ajuda. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/401796/angular-8-ngx-bootstrap-datepicker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Construa a data no formato brasileiro a partir da data que está retornando do elemento de `Thu Dec 20 2018 23:26:21 GMT-0200 (Horário de Verão de Brasília)`:

```
var dia = this.formulario.controls.data.value;
dia = dia.getDate()+"/"+Number(dia.getMonth()+1)+"/"+dia.getFullYear();
```

O resultado será : `20/12/2018`